# Common method to find index of max element in both Float and Integer array

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, floating-point, integer

This is basically to avoid redundant code. I have two different arrays, one of `Float` type and one `Integer` type. I need to find index of maximum element in both the arrays which is easy to do as I can write two different methods, one for comparing float and one for comparing Integers.

What am trying to do improve is to write just one common method which can take in either of the array as argument and can return me the max index. What I have tried unsuccessfully so far is:

```
private static int findMaxIndex(Object [] arr){
        int maxIndex =(int) IntStream.range(0,arr.length)
                  .boxed()
                  .max(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> arr[i])) // getting compiler error here
                  .map(max->arr[max])
                  .orElse(-1);
        
        
        return maxIndex;
    }
```

and am looking to call this method like this:

```
Float [] a = {0.3f, 0.5f, 0.9f, 0.7f, 0.1f};
Integer []b = {3000, 250, 100, 2000, 2000, 10246};

int maxIndexFloatArray = findMaxIndex(a);
int maxIndexIntegerArray = findMaxIndex(b);
```

Am pretty sure there are easier ways to do this, but am a bit rusty now in hands on java code. Hope this explains the question correctly.

Comment: I think you need to specify what should happen if there are nan's in the float array.  As I understand it in Java, as in C, all comparisons with a nan are false, while max(x,nan) is nan for any x.

Comment: @dmuir when you compare objects (`Float` and `Double`) rather than primitive types, [there is a defined order](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo(java.lang.Double)).

Answer (score 2):

*lambda with* `reduce` comparing `Comparable`s

```
private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int findMaxIndex(T[] arr) {
  return IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
      .reduce((l, r) -> arr[l].compareTo(arr[r]) < 0 ? r : l).orElse(-1);
}
```

for multiple max values the index of the first is returned
if You need the index of the last max value change the `<` to `<=`
`arr` can be empty but may not contain `null` values

Comment: Every solution on this page has exact as many brackets as my solution. These solutions that are using `max()` needing even 2 extra braces, because of the additional boxing with `boxed()`.

Comment: I made the lamda in a more squeezed way, what You like better. Nevertheless there are no *unnecessary brackets or braces*. I think leaving the braces around `l, r` is better for the readability than removing them. Btw. this is the shortest and fastest solution with and without the spacing.

Comment: First of all, thank You for Your time elaborating on the problems. You use eclipse too? So try Ctrl+Shift+F on my lambda. Of course I could break up at every method invocation what normaly blows up the source code a lot.
If I break the line up before the functional argument list, it doesn't get indented in eclipse. Therefore I break up the line before a `->`. The braces around the stream part is indeed a personal quirk *(which I will try to avoid in the future)*.

Comment: You know that you can configure Eclipse’s formatter? Normally, I’m not nit-picky regarding formatting but I truly had difficulties reading the original version when I read it the first time. It’s much better now and it also was a good idea to replace the raw `Comparable` with a type parameter. Note that the standard idiom is `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` (compare with [`Collections.max(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)); might be irrelevant for arrays, but it’s simpler to always use the same pattern.

Comment: I regulary stumble over this covariance/contravariance thing. Good advise.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it old fashioned:

```
private <T> int findMaxIndex(T[] arr, Comparator<T> comparator){
        int maxIndex= 0;
        T currMax = arr[0];
        for (int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
            if (comparator.compare(currMax,arr[i])<0){
                currMax = arr[i];
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }
```

And then call it like:

```
private int getMaxFloatIndex(Float[] floatArr){
        return findMaxIndex(floatArr,Float::compareTo);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Grabbing the inheritance hierarchy "from top", I would propose `Comparable<X>` as the input type for `findMaxIndex`. It is the most general type of object, of which you can distinguish a "max element":

```
private static <X extends Comparable<X>> int findMaxIndex(final X[] arr) {
    return IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
           .boxed()
           .max(
             (Integer idx1, Integer idx2) -> arr[idx1].compareTo(arr[idx2])
           )
           .orElse(-1);
}
```

For simplicity: Hoping/assuming `arr` is nor null nor contains null elements! ;) (otherwise: NPE!)

...to use it like:

```
Float[] a = { 0.3f, 0.5f, 0.9f, 0.7f, 0.1f };
Integer[] b = { 3000, 250, 100, 2000, 2000, 10246 };
System.out.println(findMaxIndex(a));
System.out.println(findMaxIndex(b));
```

Prints:

---

```
2
5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> int findMaxIndex(T[] arr)
```

This can find the index of the maximal value based on Number, the interface of all numeric types, wrapper classes and atomic wrappers.

Also a findMax might so be made. Without the numeric aspect, just Comparable suffices, say for a String[].

Comment: You have a little typo in your code snippet. The comma should be replaced by `&` in order to be syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

This one should do the trick:

```
private static <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> int findMaxIndex(T[] array) {
    if (array == null || array.length == 0) return -1;
    int largest = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].compareTo(array[largest]) > 0) largest = i;
    }
    return largest;
}
```

---

You literally tell the compiler that your generic parameter `T` should be both a `Number` and `Comparable` to the same type.